# How to configure Solr managed-schema.xml in order to store JSON Object in Solr field

Tags: java, json, solr

I want to store a JSON Object in one of the Solr 7.5.0 field.

Ex : **{
      "networkId": "1N12PREM",
      "networkDescription": "Premier"
    }**

The above JSON should be stored in one of the Solr field with name "data". I already know that above JSON object can be stored in two different fields like "data.networkId" and "data.networkDescription". Then the "managed-schema".xml would be as follows :

[Solr managed-schema.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwThN.png)

**But I dont want to store in 2 different fields ("data.networkId" & "data.networkDesription")**.

I want to store the complete above example JSON object in one Solr field with name "data". For this, I want to know how to configure "data" field in Solr "managed-schema".xml

Comment: Do you just want to store the serialized JSON content, or do you want to store an embedded, multilevel object inside the document?

Comment: I want to store serialized JSON content in "data" Solr field.

Comment: In that case a `string` field would work just fine, and you'll serialize the data when importing it to Solr (usually in your code, or if that's not possible, in an StatelessScriptProcessor in an update chain).

Comment: Even If I add JSON Object into the Solr field of type "string", Can I make a query to fetch the Solr document based on "networkId" & "networkDescription". This is my doubt/question. According to our requirement, total JSON object should be stored in one Solr field and at the same time, if I query Solr based on "networkId" & "networkDescription", I should be able to fetch the Solr document is the exact requirement.

Comment: Then that's something different. If you store the JSON directly, then no, you won't be able to query on it. But you can do both - have one field to store the JSON verbatim, then those two fields that you've already described. You can also use child documents, but this will complicate every other aspect of querying and merging documents.